# Object destructuring and converting

Tags: typescript

I have two interfaces:

```
export interface Foo {
  __typename: "Foo";
  id: string;
  name: string | null;
  otherThing: string | null;
}

export interface Bar {
  __typename: "Bar";
  id: string;
  name: string | null;
}
```

And I want to convert a object of Foo type in bar type. Can I do it inline, with object destructuring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using branded types, so not really... if `__typename` were less strict, you could duck-type Foo into Bar (but not the other way around). However, this defeats the purpose of branded types. i.e.

```
const x: Foo = { __typename: "Bar", id: '1', name: 'x', otherThing: 'otherThing' }
```

would be valid.

What's wrong with destructuring? You can still do it "inline".

```
const foo: Foo = { __typename: "Foo", id: '1', name: 'x', otherThing: 'otherThing' }
const bar: Bar = { __typename: "Bar", id: '1', name: 'y' }

const fooToBar: Bar = { ...foo, __typename: "Bar" }
const barToFoo: Foo = { ...bar, otherThing: 'otherThing', __typename: "Foo" }
```

again, keep in mind that bar -> foo is missing `otherThing`.

Edit: that's more an example of "splat-ing" rather than destructuring but the idea stands.

Answer (score 3):

Interfaces declared by TypeScript aren't "real", by which I mean they aren't intrinsic properties of objects which happen to implement them. Interfaces are simply compile-time abstractions, used for safety checks and code analysis and code completion help. There isn't anything to "convert". The objects are just objects, and you can use them anyway you like.

To convince TypeScript to accept an object being used as if it implements a particular interface that it didn't originally implement, you can *cast* that object as a different type, but nothing like destructuring or anything else that requires creating new objects or copying data is involved. The object remains its original self, and the TypeScript compiler just looks at it differently.

Oh, and just to make sure you know...

`__typename: "Foo";`

...doesn't assign the value "Foo" to `__typename`, it merely tells TypeScript that "Foo" is the only value you're allowed to assign to `__typename` in your TypeScript code, unless you use casting or other tricks to make TypeScript ignore what the interface is telling it is permissible.

Comment: Maybe say "type assertion" instead of "cast" just to drive the point home even harder.